# Why my policy is not called on laravel with with mongodb?

Tags: laravel, mongodb

With docs https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#generating-policies on laravel site with mongodb as datasource
I want to add policies to access restrictions

I created a Policy with a command :

```
php artisan make:policy ProductPolicy  --model=Product
```

in file app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php I added lines :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Policies\ProductPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        Product::class => ProductPolicy::class,
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

and in file app/Policies/ProductPolicy.php calling of the same wrapping getPolicyRule function :

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Policies;
    
    use App\Models\Product;
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
    
    class ProductPolicy
    {
        use HandlesAuthorization;
    
        public function viewAny(User $user)
        {
            return $this->getPolicyRule($user, null);
        }
    
        public function view(User $user, Product $product)
        {
            return $this->getPolicyRule($user, $product);
        }
    
        public function create(User $user)
        {
            return $this->getPolicyRule($user, null);
        }
    
        private function getPolicyRule(User $user, ?Product $product): bool
        {
            \Log::info(' -1 getPolicyRule ACCESS_APP_PRODUCTS_MANAGER::'); // BUT I DO NOT FIND THIS line in log file
            return $user->hasAnyRole(ACCESS_APP_PRODUCTS_MANAGER);
        }
    }
```

I cleared all caches with commands :

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled

composer dump-autoload
```

But My policy is not called anyway...

Did I miss something ?
I know that some laravel plugin do not with mongodb... Can it be reason of the issue ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^v10.29.0", 
"mongodb/laravel-mongodb": "^4.0.0",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you use your policy?
here is [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies) for using it

your codes seem fine, just check where you call your policy and check it with the doc

also restart php fpm if needed

Edited:

If you check the doc you will find more examples here are some useful ones:

```
$request->user()->cannot('POLICY METHOD NAME', MODEL INSTANCE)
```

like:

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post): RedirectResponse
{
    if ($request->user()->cannot('update', $post)) {
        abort(403);
    }

    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

or inside of the controller, you can use this:

```
$this->authorize('POLICY METHOD NAME', MODEL INSTANCE);
```

like:

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post): RedirectResponse
{
    $this->authorize('update', $post);

    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

also, check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-resource-controllers)

Comment: I thought that adding a line in  file app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php  will run checks automatically for any model action? Not ? Have to write calling of methods in any action of the productController ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo please check edited answer